# Python 3.3 (Using IDLE)

Tags: python3

I recently installed Python 3.3 on Centos 6 (which has Python 2.6.6 already installed).  When I try to open the the Python Shell with IDLE, it opens with Python 2.6.6.

How do I open Python 3.3 with IDLE?

Comment: On my system I have `idle` and `idle3`. Different flavor, but have you checked for tab completion options in your terminal (type idle and hit tab a few times to see if it shows other executables).

Comment: I can't believe I was overlooking tab completion!  Your solution of course worked :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubunto 16.04 system, I installed idle3: sudo apt install idle3

Then executing "idle3" brings up a Python 3 window.